# How different are tendon injuries resulting from subacromial impingement compared to epicondylopathies resulting from overuse?

Tags: tendinopathy

I wonder how different tendon injuries resulting from subacromial impingement are compared to epicondylopathies resulting from overuse, in terms of physical injuries. I.e., looking at the tendon (e.g., histopathology), would the injuries look similar, or e.g. would the injury resulting from an impingement would cause more localized micro-tears of the tendons (where the tendon got pinched), vs. epicondylopathies where micro-tears would be more spread across the tendon?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.